# Is it 'cold to touch' or 'cold to the touch'?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-article

Do you need the article 'the' in the following sentence. Please explain.

> The gun felt cold to touch.
>   The gun felt cold to the touch.

Comment: Just using **The gun felt cold** would work too.

Comment: @hjpotter92: The question is not "what other phrase means the same", but rather whether the article "the" (or the lack of it) is grammatical in the two sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Idiomatically, including ***the*** in such constructions is far more common. From Google Books...

> *...felt cold/rough to **the** touch* ([11,200](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22rough%20to%20touch%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20cold%20to%20the%20touch%22&oq=%22felt%20cold%20to%20the%20touch%22&gs_l=serp.3...34152.36466.2.36836.9.9.0.0.0.0.100.569.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab._nubFfo-SoA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1396&bih=821)/[**1070**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22rough%20to%20touch%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20rough%20to%20the%20touch%22&oq=%22felt%20rough%20to%20the%20touch%22&gs_l=serp.3...3426.3930.1.5073.4.4.0.0.0.1.121.332.2j2.4.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.WQWRtE4lWX4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1396&bih=821) instances)
>    *...felt cold to **the** touch* ([120](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22rough%20to%20touch%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20cold%20to%20touch%22&oq=%22felt%20cold%20to%20touch%22&gs_l=serp.3...238545.240630.4.240935.9.9.0.0.0.0.141.722.8j1.9.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.FIKhYG26pU0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1396&bih=821)/[**7**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22rough%20to%20touch%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22felt%20rough%20to%20touch%22&oq=%22felt%20rough%20to%20touch%22&gs_l=serp.3...5975.7180.0.7593.5.5.0.0.0.0.70.267.5.5.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.tL4YKbt14qA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1396&bih=821) instances; ***bold*** counts are for versions including ***the***)

As @hjpotter92 comments, *The gun felt cold* is also fine. There's no real difference in *meaning* between any of these forms - just a slight shift in emphasis.

When ***the*** is included, we're more inclined to interpret ***touch*** as *the **sense** of touch* (anyone's, not necessarily that of the speaker or his subject). But without ***the***, we're more included to understand it as *the **action** of **touching*** (probably performed by the speaker or his subject).

Obviously if we discard *to [the] touch* completely, the basic meaning remains the same (if the gun *feels* cold, this can only be established by *touch*). But if we consider...

> *His leg felt cold [to [the] touch].*

...then without those last 2/3 words, it's possible to understand the sentence as meaning *he **sensed** that his leg was cold* (**directly**, through the nerves in his leg, not by touching it with his fingers, etc.). The other two possibilities (that he, or someone else, touched his leg and felt the cold) are both still possible.